# Is there some way to use my Guitar Hero drum pedal on my PC?

Tags: controllers

I have a pedal from Guitar Hero World Tour, and I want to use it for push-to-talk in PC games. I don't want to have to connect the entire drum set, just the pedal. The pedal has a 3.5mm jack attached to it. Is there some way to use this on a computer and use a program like GlovePie to turn the pedal into a button?

Comment: Are you able to even get an adapter for it? (ie. Jack to USB)

Comment: I haven't tried it, but there's stuff like [this](http://www.amazon.com/3-5mm-Jack-Plug-Data-Cable/dp/B006T95XUS) that could work. Would my computer recognize it as an input device though? I don't want to drop the hefty $2 if I don't need to

Comment: That link is a good way to blow something up. It's build for a specific device and using it for a different device can break things, badly.

Answer (score 1):

I've messed around with the drum pedals for Rock Band and Guitar Hero before.  They're just simple momentary switches with a really complex case.  The 3.5mm jack is just an interface, the switch just shorts the two pins together.

What you'd need to do is convert that switch to something the PC can recognize as an input.  It might be possible to connect the 3.5mm connector to Line In and then run some software to convert the on/off signal to an input, but a quick Google search doesn't turn up anything useful there.

Ideally, though, you'd have the pedal show up as a USB Human Interface Device (HID).  I'm not aware of any currently available adapters that can do this directly, but someone with electronics expertise could probably make it work with a microcontroller that has USB HID support.  It would also be possible to salvage the logic out of an old HID device (controller, mouse, keyboard) and wire the pedal into one of the already-present switches.

If you don't have the requisite electronics expertise, I'd suggest just getting a commercially available USB HID foot pedal and ditching the one for the drum kit.  (Or, y'know, save the drums for later when RB/GH release new games...)

Comment: I modified a joystick for use as guitar foot switches. If you take the case off a joystick, each button just bridges a gap between a positive and negative lead. With 5 mins of careful soldering, you can attach leads to each side of the gap and then attach a momentary switch to the leads. If what you say is true re: the pedal, if you have a 3.5mm extension cable, all you need to do is cut the wires and solder the leads from that to the joypad button and then plug the foot pedal into it. After that, you'd need either Joy2Key or some sort of joystick emulator that can aggregate inputs.

Comment: I stopped at 3 switches for my project, but there are potentially over 12 buttons and two analog sticks. I expect you'd have resistance problems if you load too many momentary switches.

Comment: @Yorik, yeah, my pedal broke so I actually rebuilt a new one out of a LED touch light and the momentary switch from a case reset button.  Wire the switch up to the 3.5mm male connector, and you're basically done.  I did something similar to your project with an old controller to make my own "ghetto" guitar controller.  Big, bright red push buttons FTW.

Comment: guitar controller as in rockband? I use mine with Joy2Midi and an amp simulator (Simulanalog VST sort of thing)